# Add additional columns to Azure Search Blob index

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

We are planning to configure Azure Search Index for Blob containers so the content of the documents can be indexed. But we need to add additional columns such as "container name" to the index. As the indexer is automatically performing the indexing, how to customize it to add custom columns.

Comment: Answered for specific scenario of getting the container name. You mentioned that you have additional custom columns you want to add. Please add comments describing those, or feel free to contact me at eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the container name from `metadata_storage_path` by creating a field mapping (see [field mappings](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-indexer-field-mappings/)) that uses [extractTokenAtPosition function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-indexer-field-mappings/#extractTokenAtPositionFunction): 

`"fieldMappings" : [ 
  { 
    "sourceFieldName" : "metadata_storage_path", 
    "targetFieldName" : "container",
    "mappingFunction" : { "name" : "extractTokenAtPosition", "parameters" : { "delimiter" : "/", "position" : 3 } } 
  }]`

The approach behind this is to split the blob path, which looks like "https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/rest_of_path", on slashes and take the container, which is the 4th token (position = 3 since positions are zero-based).

HTH!